# Enter a string and divide it in words

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to code a program based which can compare words of a sentence or paragraph to a database, as if it were a text corrector. My problem here is that I have to enter on the console the text I want to correct as a string and then divide it in words stored in a vector of strings in C++. I tried a thousand ways but I cannot get it done.
Here is the code I last tried:

```
std::cout << "Enter the text: ";
std::string sentence;
std::vector<std::string> vText;
while (getline(std::cin, sentence)){
    std::stringstream w(sentence);
    std::string word;
    while(w >> word)
        vText.push_back(word);
}
```

When I execute this code, I got nothing, as if the program did nothing. Can you help me please?

This is the final thing (a piece):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Introduzca una frase: ";
    std::string frase;
    std::vector<std::string> vTextoAnalizar;
    while (getline(std::cin, frase)){
        std::stringstream w(frase);
        std::string palabra;
        while(w >> palabra)
            vTextoAnalizar.push_back(palabra);
    }   
    for (int i=0;i<vTextoAnalizar.size();i++){
        std::cout << vTextoAnalizar[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, "I execute this code", hm, how do you execute it? How do you check what it returns? You must give us a minimal, compilable, working example so that we can see what's happening

Comment: I wrote a kind of complete thing. But the console still does nothing:

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/18OoC8)

Comment: So, as Paul said, I cannot reproduce, either. Did you make sure to end your input with an EOF? (so, ctrl-z on windows, ctrl-d on Linux) It's always easiest to just add a few `std::cout << "I'm now doing this and that";` outputs to figure out where your program currently is. Better even: learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to stack exchange. Your question has been down voted as you have not made a reasonable effort to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please take particular note of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string>  read_text() {

    std::cout << "Enter the text: ";
    std::string sentence;
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> vText;
    while(getline(std::cin, sentence)){

        std::stringstream ss(sentence);
        while ( getline( ss, word, ' ' ) ) {
            if (word.compare("quit") == 0)
                return vText;

            vText.push_back(word);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> test_vector = read_text();

    std::cout << "Vector : " << std::endl;
    for (int i=0;i<test_vector.size();i++){
            std::cout << test_vector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This will split on spaces, and add your words to the vector at the end of each sentence. I imagine that there are more intelligent ways of parsing, but this should get your test code working.

Hope that helps.